# JSON class creation help in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I really need help creating classes for this JSON, I need to eventually loop through and add each name (example: 20th Anniversary Pack 1st Wave) and its corresponding code (example: 20AP) to a database, but to do that I need to deserialize this first and I cant work out how to create the classes, usually I generate them but when I tried that it did not work, tia

Here is **part** of my JSON string:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "setsAbbreviations": {
        "20th Anniversary Pack 1st Wave": ["20AP"],
        "20th Anniversary Pack 2nd Wave": ["20AP"],
        "Beginner's Edition 1 (2011)": ["BE01"],
        "Beginner's Edition 2 (2011)": ["BE02"],
        "Booster Chronicle": ["BC"],
        "Booster R2": ["B2"],
    }
}
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
Public Class root3
Public Property status As String
Public Property setsAbbreviations As String()
End Class
```

And this is the error: 'An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'setsAbbreviations['20th Anniversary Pack 1st Wave']', line 1, position 74.'

Comment: Questions asking for help with code need to include the code and what exactly the problem is.  `it did not work` is a feeble problem description.  As is, this is just asking for someone to write code for you and thats not what the site is about.

Comment: @Plutonix updated, don't really know what to write though.

Comment: Thats pretty weird JSON - is it something you created or get from somewhere?  `[ ... ]` means an array, but all those codes are just an array of 1; also the `20th ...` entry has the same code for 1 and 2nd wave.  The definition for `setsAbbreviations` is not correct to start with - VS and none of the other class creating robots made that - I'd change the definition to a `Dictionary(of String, String())`

Comment: The JSON is from an API, its the only API I could find that listed both sets and codes in one go.

Comment: And know it wasnt a robot that did that, It was my terrible attempt, when the class creation tool did it, it was about 50 pages long and didn't work xD

Comment: You should excise "didnt work" from your vocabulary.  It is not the least bit helpful to someone trying to help/debug based solely on what you say/describe.  As I said, `Dictionary(of String, String())` will work fine.

Comment: Sorry I'm not entirely sure what that means. I don't really understand this all that much, I'm just used to using a class generator up until this point.

Comment: I did try and I got this error: 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Comment: From 30 mins ago: `The definition for setsAbbreviations is not correct to start with  ... I'd change the definition to a Dictionary(of String, String())`  rather than `As String()`.  The keys will be those names `"Booster R2"` and the value will be an array of 1 containing the code `"B2"`